# Delete all except a range of columns excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have hundreds of Columns in excel that I don't need. I have a range that I want to keep.

At the minute I have

```
Sub DeleteClms ()
    Range("A:G,L:O").Delete
End Sub
```

Is there anyway to make this an opposite, in other languages I would simply put a =!. 
I have tried putting <> in but I dont know where/how to put it into my code?

Thanks

Comment: hmmmm, not sure you can use <>, If I were in your situation I would just record a macro and select all the columns I want deleted. Then go in and tidy up a bit.

Comment: No - there isn't an equivalent direct approach in VBA for this. The closest would be copying the range you want elsehwere, rather than deleting the range you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Excel or VBA function for the Symetric Difference of the columns that I know of.

Here is a quick VBA function to get there.  Usage would be `DeleteAllBut Range("A:C,H:Q")`

```
Sub DeleteAllBut(rngToKeep As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngToDelete As Range
    Dim rngColi As Range

    'Number of columns used in worksheet
    Set ws = rngToKeep.Parent
    iCols = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    FirstOne = True
    For i = 1 To iCols
        Set rngColi = Range("A:A").Offset(0, i - 1)
        If Intersect(rngToKeep, rngColi) Is Nothing Then
            If FirstOne Then
                Set rngToDelete = rngColi
                FirstOne = False
            Else
                Set rngToDelete = Union(rngColi, rngToDelete)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    Debug.Print rngToDelete.Address & " was deleted from " & ws.Name
    rngToDelete.Delete


End Sub
```